# How to report stats on restore via sqlcmd?

Tags: sql-server, restore, sqlcmd

I've inherited a batch file script that calls `sqlcmd` with parameters. One of the parameters is the path to a SQL file. That file includes a database `restore` command. The command in the SQL file includes the parameter `stats = 1` but nothing is reported in the commandline window during a restore.

Is it possible to use `sqlcmd` this way to initiate a database restore *and* have the stats report back and displayed on the commandline as the restore executes? If not, then can you point me to alternative approaches?

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE: 2018-12-20** - I completely re-wrote my answer to use `Powershell`.  Perhaps this solution will work for you.

---

I believe `SQLCMD` was rewritten for 2012 in such a way that `print` statements and even `raiserror` messages issued during a run via `SQLCMD` never displayed until the entire job finished.

If using `Powershell` is an option, you can use the `Invoke-SqlCmd` cmdlet to run your scripts.  To see the output while the script is running, include the `-Verbose` parameter.  (you'll also want to include something like `-QueryTimeout 0` to keep the script from timing out at the default 30 seconds)

Here is a quick way to test this functionality.

Create the following stored procedure which issues `raiserror` statements every 10 seconds (for 50 iterations) and displays the current timestamp.  Under normal runs of `SQLCMD`, you wouldn't see any output until the procedure completely finishes.  However, using `INVOKE-SQLCMD` and the `-Verbose` parameter, you will see the output as the script runs

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS [scutility].[SqlCmdTestOutput]
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE [scutility].[SqlCmdTestOutput]
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @count INT = 50
    DECLARE @msg VARCHAR(8000)

    WHILE @count > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @msg = convert(VARCHAR(50), sysdatetime())

        RAISERROR (@msg,0,1) WITH NOWAIT

        WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:10'

        SET @count -= 1
    END
END
```

---

```
--The powershell command
powershell.exe  -command "Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance '.' -Query '[scutility].[SqlCmdTestOutput]' -Database SCUTILITY -Verbose -QueryTimeout 0"

--output
C:\>powershell.exe  -command "Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance '.' -Query '[scutility].[SqlCmdTestOutput]' -Database SCUTILITY -Verbose -QueryTimeout 0"
VERBOSE: 2018-12-20 08:12:24.3689374
VERBOSE: 2018-12-20 08:12:34.3696751
VERBOSE: 2018-12-20 08:12:44.3704152
VERBOSE: 2018-12-20 08:12:54.3710561
VERBOSE: 2018-12-20 08:13:04.3717697
```

---

You can also eliminate the string 'VERBOSE:' from the output by *redirecting* the `-Verbose` output and using `Write-Host`.

```
C:\>powershell.exe  -command "Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance '.' -Query '[scutility].[SqlCmdTestOutput]' -Database SCUTILITY -Verbose 4>&1 -QueryTimeout 0 | % {Write-Host ($_.Message)}"
2018-12-20 08:42:59.9874559
2018-12-20 08:43:09.9891544
2018-12-20 08:43:19.9898284
2018-12-20 08:43:29.9905699
2018-12-20 08:43:39.9912415
2018-12-20 08:43:49.9919723
2018-12-20 08:43:59.9936545
2018-12-20 08:44:09.9943466
2018-12-20 08:44:19.9960623
2018-12-20 08:44:29.9967689
```

Comment: I both love this approach and am scared by it at the same time :D I'll give it a go though and report back.

Comment: @youcantryreachingme - we have not encountered any abnormal issues with this approach.  Your mileage may vary.  I'd be interested in the results of your testing.

Comment: No success. Downloaded 2008 R2 Command Line Utilities from MS site here (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=16978) Install said I required Native Client, which I downloaded from same page. Installed both. Found SQLCMD. Confirmed version via license text file. Moved two files to our dev server. Copied your script. Adjusted path. Called `%SQLCMD% with our parameters. Error: application failed to start because its side-by-side configuration is incorrect. MS sol'n requires regedit. Debating my options at this point.

Comment: Following link may help with the error I encountered. Will have to work on this one a little more. https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2018/03/21/sql-server-fix-error-14001-application-failed-start-side-side-configuration-not-correct/

Comment: @youcantryreachingme - interesting, we do not encounter the error you’re getting, although the native client issue does sound familiar- sorry to hear it’s not turning out as easy as I’d hoped

Comment: @youcantryreachingme - it probably doesn't make a difference, but wanted to share details about my sqlcmd.exe (fileversion 2007.100.4000.0) and sqlcmd.rll (datemodified 7/10/2009 7:58am).  These are most likely plain SQL 2008 and not R2.  I just restested my example on a completely different server.  I created the c:\SQL2008_SQLCMD folder and placed the sqlcmd.exe and sqlcmd.rll files to that folder.  I did have to install the SQL native client (date modified 6/22/2012 9:34am).  Ran my %sqlcmd% test and it worked without issues.  uncertain why you're having the problem you're having. :(

Comment: Thanks @Scott Hodgin. My event error log reports the file Microsoft.VC80.ATL "could not be found". Any chance you can search yours and let me know where that file should ordinarily reside?

Comment: @youcantryreachingme - I can't find that file on my system, which is strange since I'm not having any problems and you are.  You might try downloading the Visual C++ 2008 package from here https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29

Comment: @youcantryreachingme - I updated my answer to use Powershell.  Perhaps that is an option for you.

Comment: The `invoke-sqlcmd` is part of the sqlps powershell module, and doesn't depend on installing the sqlcmd.exe commandline tool.  It is a separate installation.  If you have neither the commandline tools nor the sqlps powershell module, powershell can use the built-in .NET SqlClient with SqlConnection, SqlCommmand, etc to run commands.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft - Thanks for the additional information.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to do this in PowerShell without the SQL Server commandline tools or the SQLPS module.

This sample runs a single batch and outputs the messages like SSMS does, formatting errors differently from information messages and print output:

```
$sql = @"
  backup database adventureworksdw2017 
  to disk='c:\temp\aw.bak' with init, format, stats=1

  select 1/0
"@

$constr = "server=.;database=master;integrated security=true"
$con = new-object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection $constr

$con.Open()
$con.FireInfoMessageEventOnUserErrors = $true
$handler = [System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInfoMessageEventHandler] {param($sender, $event) 

   foreach ( $error in $event.Errors)
   {

     [System.Data.SqlClient.SqlError] $e = $error

     if ($e.Class -gt 10)
     {
       $Host.UI.WriteErrorLine("Msg $($e.Number), Level $($e.Class), State $($e.State), Line $($e.LineNumber)")
       $Host.UI.WriteErrorLine($e.Message)
     }
     else
     {
       Write-Host $e.Message
     }

   }

 }
$con.add_InfoMessage( $handler )

$cmd = $con.CreateCommand()
$cmd.CommandText = $sql 
$cmd.CommandTimeout = 0

$rowcount = $cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

$con.Close()
```